# Are we charged for .validate() reads?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Given path

`/user-project-enum/{uid}/{pid}`

Where `{pid}` is a project identifier and it's value is a string enum.

Eg,

```
myuserid
    project_id1: favorites
    project_id2: trash
    project_id3: inbox
    project_id4: favorites
```

I have the opportunity to test if `{pid}` exists in path `/projects/{pid}` using `.validate()`

However, each project object is about 5kB, which could bring the write cost up from nothing (writes are free IIRC) to the cost of a 5kB read if we are charged for reads performed by `.validate()`. If not, this type of operation is very cheap and a no-brainer.

So my question is this, are we charged for `.validate()` reads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Firebase Realtime Database charges for egress bandwidth, and the database storage space only. It does not charge for read or write operations beyond that.

Firebase Realtime Database security rules don't charge for bandwidth of the data that they read. Since this is traffic that remains internal to Google infrastructure, it is considered uncharged bandwidth.

---

This is different for Cloud Firestore. Since Firestore charges for document reads (in addition to bandwidth, and storage space used), the documents you read in your security rules are charged against your quota.

Comment: This is the first time I have heard it described this way, and it makes perfect sense. Something I have never been able to get a direct answer on is this, which I hope you can answer directly: Does Firebase Realtime Database charge for ingress? (Upload from outside of Google infrastructure to Realtime Database.)

Comment: Not anymore as far as I know. That's why the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) only shows "GB downloaded" as a paid item.